# How do I add a JLabel[] to a JTable?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, jlabel

I have an array of JLabels which I want to add to a JTable. I tried using

```
 myJTable.add(myJLabelArray);
```

Hoping it would work, but it doesn't (Obviously, otherwise I wouldn't be here).

Can somebody please help?

Comment: `JLabels` are just component text representations. Can you not just add the text of the labels?

Comment: @Reimeus, i would, but I want the background to be coloured. Is there a way of changing the background colour of the JTable cells?

Comment: I'd say to forget adding the `JLabels`, add the text and use a `TableCellRenderer`. Have a look at _[Editors & Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) method is not the way to add components to a `JTable`. Components should never be added directly to a `JTable` or its `TableModel`.

`JLabels` are just Swing components that render text.

You can use a `TableCellRenderer`. Have a look at [Editors & Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add myJTable.add(myJLabelArray). As Reimeus pointed out use Renderers

```
  jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new Renderer()); //set column1 with jlabel
```

Your render should extend DefaulttableCellRenderer

```
 class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
  JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

 //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sample.png"));

 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
  boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
lbl.setText("hello");
//lbl.setIcon(icon);
return lbl;
}
}
```