# How to add image and text in same JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on my first project in Java in which I want the image (for profile photo) and text (for name) to be in same cell of the JTable. I have read many already asked ques Eg. [How to Insert Image into JTable Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941372/how-to-insert-image-into-jtable-cell), [How do I add a JLabel[] to a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974108/how-do-i-add-a-jlabel-to-a-jtable) but from none of them I got my answer. So can anybody help me in this?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941372/how-to-insert-image-into-jtable-cell) will solve your problem if you try to implement it

Comment: if above won't work, read about `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and implement it

Comment: both can...I did second one before with success..

Comment: ok let my try it . thx, for help.

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: Well, [that's one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659273/jtable-image-render-is-taking-too-much-load-in-application/25660413#25660413)